# How to target screen query only in IE 10+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, jquery-selectors

I'm using the flex-box property and trying to target div on IE 10+ `@media only screen and (max-width: 960px)` but I haven't found a way to accomplish that. I used this `@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none),
(-ms-high-contrast: active) {
selector here...
}` at the end of my CSS code but that didn't work.

here's a simple code of what I'm trying to do.

```css
.main {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 2px solid red;
 min-height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 960px;
 
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

.L, .R {
 flex-basis: 48%;
 /*for IE */
 /* flex-basis: calc(48% - 24px); */
 border: 2px dotted blue;
 height: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .L, .R {
  flex-basis: 90%;
  /*for IE ** how can I add this only for IE 10+ ** */
 /* flex-basis: calc(90% - 24px); */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 .main {
  justify-content: center;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="L">
 </div>
 <div class="R">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to target screen for IE 10+ (only) in css, but using special css file for IE only or Javascript would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://philipnewcomer.net/2014/04/target-internet-explorer-10-11-css/) forum post, the right way to make a media query work for only IE10+ is to do it like this:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
     .L, .R {
        flex-basis: calc(48% - 24px);
     }
}



@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active), (max-width: 768px) {
     .L, .R {
        flex-basis: calc(90% - 24px);
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for! I said in the post that I used it but didn't accomplish my goal.

Comment: This is the only way though

Comment: I was wondering if there's a way to select screen queries for IE only

Comment: In my code example I show you exactly how you can make a media querie for ie10+ only. In the 2nd example you see that I added (max-width: 768px) which is basically a combination of IE + screen

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this->**


@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
/* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
}
```